# Simple explanation of Erlang atom

Tags: erlang

I am learning Erlang and stuck trying to understand the concept of atoms. I know Python: What is a good explanation of these "atoms" in simple terms, or analogously with Python. So far, my understanding is that the type is like a string but without string operations?

Comment: Python has nothing similar.

Comment: @rightføld I see. I've modified my question now.

Comment: It is more like integers but without arithmetic. The value of `1` is `1` : what you see is what you get.

Answer (score 7):

[Docs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id64566) say that:

> An atom is a literal, a constant with name.

Sometimes you have couple of options, that you would like to choose from. In C for example, you have `enum`:

```
enum Weekday { Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday };
```

In C, it is really an integer, but you can use it in code as one of options. Atoms in Erlang are very useful in pattern matching. Lets consider very simple server:

```
loop() ->
    receive
        {request_type_1, Request} ->
            handle_request_1(Request),
            loop();
        {request_type_2, Request} ->
            handle_request_2(Request),
            loop();
        {stop, Reason} ->
            {ok, Reason};
        _ ->
            {error, bad_request}
    end.
```

Your server receives messages, that are two element tuples and uses atoms to differentiate between different types of requests: `request_type_1`, `request_type_2` and `stop`. It is called pattern matching.

Server also uses atoms as return values. `ok` atom means, that everything went ok. `_` matches everything, so in case, that simple server receives something unexpected, it quits with tuple `{error, Reason}`, where the reason is also atom `bad_request`.

Boolean values `true` and `false` are also atoms. You can build logical functions using function clauses like this:

```
and(true, true) ->
    true;
and(_, _) ->
    false.

or(false, false) ->
    false;
or(_, _) ->
    true.
```

(It is a little bit oversimplified, because you can call it like this: `or(atom1, atom2)` and it will return `true`, but it is only for illustration.)

Module names in Erlang are also atoms, so you can bind module name to variable and call it, for example type this in Erlang shell:

```
io:format("asdf").
Variable = io.
Variable:format("asdf").
```

You should not use atoms as strings, because they are not garbage collected. If you start creating them dynamically, you can run out of memory. They should be only used, when there is fixed amount of options, that you type in code by hand. Of course, you can use the same atom as many times as you want, because it always points to the same point in memory (an atom table).

They are better than C enums, because the value is known at runtime. So while debugging C code, you would see `1` instead of `Tuesday` in debugger. Using atoms doesn't have that disadvantage, you will see `tuesday` in your both in your code and Erlang shell.

Answer (score 3):

Also, they're often used to tag a tuple, for descriptiveness. For example:

{age, 42}

Rather than just

42

Answer (score 2):

Atom is a literal constant. Has no value but can be used as a value. Examples are: true, false, undefined. If you want to use it as a string, you need to apply atom_to_list(atom) to get a string (list) to work with. Module names are also atoms.
Take a look at http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html

Comment: To be really strict an atom does have a value, itself. So the value of foo is foo, bar is bar, etc. The erlang shell is a REPL and when you enter an atom it evaluates it and prints the result, the atom itself which is its value. It is the same with numbers and other atomic datatypes, they evaluated to them selves.